# How to learn kendo dropdownlist is enabled or disabled in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I want to learn kendo dropdownlist is enabled or disabled for using in a if function.

For example if kendo dropdownlist is enabled my return value true, otherwise false

How can I do that?

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do very simply with

```
$('#selectId').prop('disabled');
```

In disabling, KendoUI disabled too the select, so :

```
var state = $('#selectId').prop('disabled');
```

Comment: if someone is needing this for a selenium test it's available as a nuget package: https://github.com/leblancmeneses/RobustHaven.IntegrationTests/commit/2557440fb98d8e267f0b2d94365dd37cb7ad376a

Comment: Work fine with control created with JQuery, not working with control created with MVC Widget

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
$("#your_dropdown_id").attr("aria-disabled");
```

If it is disabled this returns true else it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#your_dropdown_id').data("kendoDropDownList").options.enabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

BENARD Patrick's answer is correct.

Below also worked for me(alternative solution):

```
<script>
  $("#selectionKendoList").kendoDropDownList({
    enable: false
  });
  
  if($("#selectionKendoList").parent().find(".k-dropdown-wrap").hasClass("k-state-disabled")) {
    alert("Disabled");
  }
  else {
    alert("Enabled");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not working for recent versions of Kendo